# Why does Vue update variable in parent - no event used

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

According to [Vue.js docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#one-way-data-flow) (Components: One-Way data Flow) I assumed that I'm not able to update parent's variable from child component.

How is it possible, that when I bind a variable to child component, it is updated without emitting any event?

Here is [Vue SFC playground example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

How can I use a copy of variable in child component without propagating changes to parent?

Edit: I'm curious why the property `userAccount` in `AccountPage.vue` gets updated.

There's **no v-model**, no events submitted, yet it still gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
In AccountForm.Vue an reactive and mutable ref object is created when writing

```
 const userAccount = ref ({..})
```

Changing the reactive object will affect the parent. If you remove the ref() you'll see that the parent isn't updated.

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref

Old answer:
When you use v-model you create a two-way data binding. V-model is a shorthand for v-bind and input, that is you bind data to child via v-bind and receive data via input event that is emitted from child.

So,

```
<input v-model="searchText">
```

is the same as writing

```
<input
  v-bind:value="searchText"
  v-on:input="searchText = $event.target.value"
>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Comment: There is not a v-model or two-way binding on the component.

Comment: Isn't there a <input type=text v-model="record.firstName"> in AccountForm.Vue?

Comment: Sure. But the data comes from a prop from the parent which is not a v-model.

Answer (score 0):

The example demonstrates the usage of `v-model` and as stated in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

> Custom events can also be used to create custom inputs that work with
> v-model. Remember that:
>
> `<input v-model="searchText">`
>
> does the same thing as:
>
> `<input v-bind:value="searchText" v-on:input="searchText = $event.target.value">`

meaning it does fire an event

Comment: There is not a v-model or two-way binding on the component.

Comment: Look at line 7 on AccountForm.vue (the 3rd tab)

Comment: Read my comment again. There is not a v-model on the component.

Comment: As @tauzN commented, you're looking to wrong component. AccountForm.vue is a child component, I'm curious why the parent variable gets updated. There's no v-model used in parent.